# How to access the SDK name in MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, msbuild

I have a C# SDK projectfile:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
</Project>
```

How do I get the SDK name as variable?

Usecase:
I have a quite big solution, containing WPF projects as well as library-projects, and I like to configure the TargetFramework in a `Directory.Build.props` file.
However I have to distinguish between WPF projects and non WPF projects to set the right TargetFramework.
I like to check if `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` is selected or not.
Currently I rely on a specific project nomenklatur (Name contains .Wpf), which is quite hacky.

```
            <Choose>
                <!--   - HACK to apply net7.0-windows to all Wpf-Projects-->
                <When Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectName.Contains(`.Wpf`))' == 'true'">
                    <PropertyGroup>
                        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
                    </PropertyGroup>
                </When>
                <Otherwise>
                    <PropertyGroup>
                        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
                    </PropertyGroup>
                </Otherwise>
            </Choose>
```

Comment: It appears that the project SDK is not available as a property or as a member of an item collection. However, the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` SDK for WPF appears to define a `_MicrosoftWindowsDesktopSdkImported` property with a value of `true`. You can test for that property instead of testing the file name.

Comment: @JonathanDodds That worked! Thanks!.  Via:  <Choose>
                <When Condition="'$(_MicrosoftWindowsDesktopSdkImported)' == 'true'">
                    <PropertyGroup>
                        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
                    </PropertyGroup>
                </When>
                <Otherwise>
                    <PropertyGroup>
                        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
                    </PropertyGroup>
                </Otherwise>
            </Choose>

Comment: I wrote up an answer with info on how to find something similar for other SDKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SDK` attribute on the [`Project` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/project-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) creates implicit imports. This can also be done with the [`Sdk` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/sdk-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022). A project can declare multiple SDKs and a given SDK can pull in multiple other SDKs.

It appears that the project SDKs are not available as a property or as an item collection.

However, an SDK may define a property or an item collection that is unique to the SDK. Testing that the property or item collection is not empty shows that the SDK was imported.

The `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` SDK for WPF appears to define a `_MicrosoftWindowsDesktopSdkImported` property with a value of `true`. You can test for that property instead of testing the file name.

Two approaches to finding something to test for:

- Check the source code of the .NET project SDK. "[Available SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#available-sdks)" lists some of the Microsoft project SDKs and their repos.
- Run a [`-preprocess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022) on the project file and examine the output to see what is imported and defined.

Comment: saved my week. Thank you!